# format statement inside a for loop

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to print a tuple in a file as:

```
for row in s:
    # Loop over columns.
    for column in row:
        print(column, type(column), end=" ")
        of1.write("%s  " % column)
        #of1.write("{:<10}{:<8}{:<23}{:<20}\n".format(row))
        of1.write("\n")
        print(end="\n")
```

all the elements are str as from the output of print statement:

```
64.08K <class 'str'> 20.0 <class 'str'> 0.95 <class 'str'> 1.7796943385724604e-05 <class 'str'>
```

The code works fine, but as obvious, not well formatted. I am trying to use format statement
for better formatting as in the commented line, but it is giving error:

```
File "eos_res.py", line 54, in <module>
    of1.write("{:<10}{:<8}{:<23}{:<20}\n".format(row))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass the whole row as *one value to format*. Use:

```
of1.write("{:<10}{:<8}{:<23}{:<20}\n".format(*row))
```

to have Python pass the individual values of `row` to `.format()`.

Alternatively, use a format that pulls out individual indexes from the one positional argument:

```
of1.write("{0[0]:<10}{0[1]:<8}{0[2]:<23}{0[3]:<20}\n".format(row))
```